# Reusing methods from other blocks in custom block

Tags: magento2, blocks, methods, code-reuse

Having a custom Block where I fetch custom data what is the accepted workaround to inject the methods in this custom Block from another block.

Having the following situation I fetch in my custom block the most viewed products I would like to reuse the methods and template from ListProducts. Is there a way to do this without extending the above class?

Comment: Do you want to call method from one block to another block?

Comment: yes for example ListProduct `getAddToCartPostParams`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below code in your block:

```
$block =  $this->getLayout()->createBlock('your-block-classnmae');

$block->getAddToCartPostParams();
```

Comment: can you explain a bit please do I place this in template or class? what is actually doing?

Comment: Yes you can place it in template file.It will create a block instance, you can access block method using it.

Comment: so I place in custom template the name of my block class `TopSellers` which is extending ` \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template` but I get error `undefined Block-Type`

Comment: you need to use `$this->getLayout()->createBlock('Modulename\Namespace\Block\TopSellers ');`